# How to remap deleting a word in insert mode?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

My terminal emulator in which I use vim is alacritty, and I want the key combination `control + backspace` to do the same that `control + w` does when in insert mode (i.e. delete the entire last word). So far I've tried to add `imap <C-Back> <C-W>` to my `.vimrc` which however doesn't seem to change anything. Does someone have an idea how to achieve the desired behaviour?

The terminal emulator I'm using is alacritty, os is arco linux.

Comment: Usually, vim is not able to distinguish between `Ctrl+Backspace` and just `Backspace`, so this might be the reason why this is happening. There are features that make distinguishing between these possible (see `:help modifyOtherKeys`), but that depends on the exact terminal you're using. Maybe [edit] your question to give more information about your setup, which O.S., which terminal emulator, etc.

Comment: @filbranden ok, I've edited my question

Comment: Note that backspace is spelled `<BS>` in `:help key-notation`, so you would need `<C-BS>`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for pointing out, I've already tried out both.